# Swift IOS keep view controller running in background after pop

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

My app consists of two views. The first one is a `GMSMapView` and the second one is used to connect to a Bluetooth device that sends coordinates.

After the Bluetooth device is connected, I use a delegate to send the information back to the map view and move a marker around. To transition between views I was previously using segues, this didn't stop the Bluetooth view controller and the data made its way like I wished to the map view.

I ran into the problem of my map view being reinitiated so I decided to use a navigation controller. Now I use a push segue to get to my second view, and pop to come back to the same instance of the first one. Great, that worked! The issue I have now is that popping the second view seems to stop it completely from running in the background like it used to. Is there a way to keep it running in the background like it did before?

What I'm currently using to pop the second view is

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Any idea would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to have the same transition without having the view controller destroyed?  Meaning, is there a way to transition from first view to second view and then back while retaining the instance of the first view?

Comment: Yes, and I've given an answer that tells you what it is — but I've also warned you that this is a bad idea and indicates that your app architecture is probably wrong.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using Swift 2.x. That version of Swift is now officially dead. You need to update.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Swift version is correlated to what xCode version you are running right? Currently have a very old MacBook air (the only one at my work place) so I'll have to see if it can even make the jump

Comment: Xcode 8.3 will run only under Sierra, alas. But Xcode 8.2 will allow you to update to Swift 3, and will run on El Capitan. The jolt to your code — the differences between Swift 2 and Swift 3 — will be very dramatic and far-reaching, so the sooner you make this transformation, the better.

Comment: App is only a few days old, like my knowledge of iOS and swift, I think the change won't be too bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140106/discussion-between-lhbortho-and-matt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A popped view controller does not "stop running". It is returned to you, and if you don't retain it, *it is completely destroyed*.

If you don't want that to happen, retain it when it is returned. You are currently ignoring the returned view controller:

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Instead, keep a reference to it:

```
self.mySecondViewController = 
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Be warned, however, that this is a very unusual architecture. You will not be able to use the storyboard segue to push again, because it will push a different copy. It would be better to abandon your navigation controller architecture entirely, as it is completely unsuited to the idea of a view controller persisting after it is popped. If you want an architecture where two view controllers persist simultaneously, you would be better off using a UITabBarController — or, even better, reorganize your app *completely*. The notion that you need the view controller to persist after being popped is a "bad smell": it means that you have put the functionality in the wrong place. Put the functionality in a place that *does* persist, rather than forcing the view controller to persist in some artificial way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt, I am completely new to iOS so the is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I will try to find another way to have my two views be persistent. Perhaps I can move my Bluetooth functionalities back to my main view controller so I do not need to have a second view controller running at the same time.

Comment: "Perhaps I can move my Bluetooth functionalities back to my main view controller so I do not need to have a second view controller running at the same time" Good idea! That's just the sort of thing I'm encouraging you to try doing.

Comment: I previously tried doing just that but with no success. Using a UITabBarController looks like it would be easy to get working but it might not be using it the correct way. I'll give the right way a little more effort before go to a UITabBarController though. Thanks!